# c# - how to convert checkbox,datetime picker and textbox value to integer

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Thanks to those who replied, your solutions were spot on !
@ to the messageboard ..apologies for overloading the question and not being specific.

I have been experimenting with what I have been given as solutions and in order to keep things consistent as per the solutions offered I have the following code:

```
var mystr = String.Format("{0},{1:yyyy,M,d,H,m,s},{2:yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}",
                this.textBox3.Text,    //0
                this.dateTimePicker1.Value,//1
                    this.dateTimePicker2.Value,//2
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox1.Checked),//3
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox2.Checked),//4
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox3.Checked),//5
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox4.Checked),//6
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox5.Checked),//7
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox6.Checked),//8
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox7.Checked),//9
                    Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox8.Checked));//10

            textBox1.Text = mystr;
            MessageBox.Show("The value entered is:  " + mystr , " Alarm DATA", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

On clicking an OK button I have a string of values namely :
88,2015,5,17,22,6,53,2015,05,17,22,06,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

I am going to be sending these to an Arduino via serial, the problem is the format they are in at the moment.

The arduino is expecting them in the same format (data type) as one would send from the serial terminal window and without a newline character added.
(Which currently is working when I type this 88,2015,5,17,22,6,53,2015,05,17,22,06,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 into a serial terminal window.

My question is how to I set/change the value of the variable mystr to what the arduino needs ?

I am currently using Serial.parseint() on the Arduino to receive the values separated by commas and load them into variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

D

> For reference ..Here's my original question:
>
> I have created a Windows form which currently has 9 checkboxes (I
>   don't know if this was the right choice.) as well as a button and 2
>   textbox.
>
> At the moment I type dates into the textboxes in the form of
>   YYYY,MM,DD,hh,mm,ss and then I select checkbox values which when
>   selected should return a 1 and if un-selected a 0.
>
> I realize this may seem like a very basic question but I can't seem to
>   find the answers I'm looking for.
>
> I would like the following to happen when I click the button :
>
> A single string get's generated/created. (Eventually I will send this
>   out via serial. (not sure if this is the variable type I should be
>   using and I would appreciate and example for both if at all possible).
>
> The string/int/message comprises of the two dates ( or as unix
>   timestamps or an option for either) and each checkbox value (either a
>   0 or a 1) << this is where I battling to find info on as well as the
>   datetime picker)
>
> So the actual string would look something like this :
>   2015,4,30,3,0,5,2015,4,30,3,0,10,0,1,0,0 (where the format is
>   date1,date2,checkbox1,checkbox2,checkbox3,checkbox4)
>
> I can currently use the checkbox.text fields but I would prefer to
>   just get the value from each as a zero or 1 to build my
>   string/int/message.
>
> I am using C# VS express.

Comment: sure would help if you would post some actual code in regards to what you have tried as well as what you are trying to do..

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest using a `DateTimePicker` to enter the date and time.  You can have it display whatever format you like and it will handle validation for you, which ensures the user never enters an invalid format or an invalid value.  You could then do something like this:

```
var str = String.Format("{0:yyyy,M,d,H,m,s},{1:yyyy,M,d,H,m,s},{2},{3},{4}",
                        this.dateTimePicker1.Value,
                        this.dateTimePicker2.Value,
                        Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox1.Checked),
                        Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox2.Checked),
                        Convert.ToInt32(this.checkBox3.Checked));
```

If you want something more generic, try this:

```
var dates = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                         .OfType<DateTimePicker>()
                         .Select(dtp => dtp.Value.ToString("yyyy,M,d,H,m,s"));
var bools = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                         .OfType<CheckBox>()
                         .Select(cb => Convert.ToInt32(cb.Checked).ToString());
var str = String.Join(",", dates.Concat(bools).ToArray());
```

That will work with any number of controls with any names.  The one caveat is that the z-order of each group of controls must match the order you want their output to appear in the final `String`.  You can adjust the z-order by dragging and dropping in the Document Outline window, which can be opened from the View > Other Windows menu.

Comment: Isn't OP asking for c#?

Comment: @MickyDuncan, bugger!  I spend more time addressing VB questions than C# around here and I forgot that this was a C# question.  I'll replace the code with C#.

Comment: Not a problem.  Your revised answer is even better!

Comment: @ Ben ..thank you kindly ! @jmcilhinney Thank you , really much appreciated. @ both of you ..those answers were both spot on. @ Moderators ..please would you re-open my question as I would really appreciate some guidance , a nudge and a glimmer of light ços I'm almost at wits end with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = null;

if (checkbox.checked)
    s = "1";
else
    s = "0";
```